# in linearmodels is the *.f_statistic null hypothesis really that "All parameters ex. constant not zero"?

Tags: linearmodels

The documentation on https://bashtage.github.io/linearmodels/panel/panel/linearmodels.panel.results.RandomEffectsResults.f_statistic.html?highlight=f%20statistic#linearmodels.panel.results.RandomEffectsResults.f_statistic reports that *.f_statistic is a classical "Classical F-stat..  Joint test of significance for non-constant regressors." In which case I read up and the null is that the model with no independent variables fits the data as well as the model.

---

However, when calling the actual string value of the null element of the code, it says "H0: All parameters ex. constant not zero" ... quite the opposite.

Was the null just incorrectly documented in the code? this was linearmodels 4.17 btw... thanks!

**Screen shot of results.**

[image]

Comment: please no images of output or errors

Comment: Typo in the code.  Should be H0: All parameters ex. constant zero.

Comment: Fixed in the main branch of linearmodels.